# How do I get the sum of someone's earnings across multiple sheets where it would only sum if given that person's name in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am currently stuck trying to create a formula for a sheet that would tally up the total earnings of a vendor throughout the month across multiple sheets(23 to be exact) and I'm not sure if I just have to SUMIFS or create an array that would go across each sheet and sum if the condition as met.

link to sheets:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BNl2lTR-dLDkiQ2aXWvHN_nOX-kN7AqE4ZGOU2DQdis/edit?usp=sharing

I tried to SUMIFS and put each sheet manually but I wouldn't get a return or it simply would not tally if I entered any data into the other sheets.

Comment: The shared sheet has *restricted access*

Comment: Sorry I just have you access now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out in cell B2 of the last tab

```cpp
=MAP(A2:A17,
   LAMBDA(vendor,
     REDUCE(,ARRAYFORMULA("March "&SEQUENCE(31)),   
       LAMBDA(tot,tab,
         tot+IFERROR(
           SUMPRODUCT(
             INDIRECT(tab&"!A:A")=vendor,
             INDIRECT(tab&"!F:F")))))))
```